# Launch image gone in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm making an app for iOS 8 and over.The app was initially targeted for 9.2 as a mistake, which I later changed to 7 and back to 8 during testing. As I changed it to 7.0 from 9.2, the image displayed by my LaunchScreen `StoryBoard` went away. The background still shows, and I am able to display labels, etc there without problems.

the filename is plain like "something.png".

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Recreate storyboard file and design for launch screen
- Remove image and re-add
- Clean project
- Checked for any obvious mistakes in project settings

many sites tell you to move to using an asset solution, though I'd prefer to use the storyboard solution.

**Does anyone have a clue on why this is and how to fix it?**

Comment: Have you tried going back to a commit prior to your change?

Comment: @AdrianB I did earlier and it worked, but I didn't know the cause of the problem (seems to be deployment target changing) - so I managed to do the same again. I would highly prefer to not go back at the moment as I've done quite some changes and transporting those to an earlier version is a lot of work

Comment: While not an answer, my comment regarding handling launch images is .. holy crap, what a mess. There seems to be something amiss internally as it is a nightmare trying to reset images/settings within an xib and seeing the *saved* file actually show on startup. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't and as yet, i have not uncovered ANY reason for the issues. When you start just deleting a setting, hitting save, then resetting a setting, over and over, and seeing differing end-results, you know something is wrong.